# GIT rebase issues

Tags: git, github

**Origin/Master:**
File1.txt
File2.txt

**LocalFeature:**
File2.txt

- git checkout LocalFeature
- git pull origin master

Then I would have following files in LocalFeature
File1.txt
File2.txt (resolve conflicts after automerge)

---

### Case2:

File1.txt
File2.txt

**LocalFeature:**
File2.txt

- git checkout LocalFeature
- git fetch
- git rebase
  always makes File2.txt conflict even after git add, git commit -m 'mess', git push

Doing a git rebase again gets here File2.txt conflict
Doing a git rebase again gets here File2.txt conflict

I'm struck here can anyone help me on this. I don't want to use git pull at all

Comment: Your question is not clearly written and it's hard to understand. Please, try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but after solving conflicts on `File2.txt` you don't need to commit those changes. What you need to do is stage the changes and signal git to continue the rebase

```
vim File2.txt   // solve your conflicts and save the file

git add File2.txt

git rebase --continue  // or --skip, depending on how you solve your conflicts
```